# how can we find such a counterexample for a nearly uniformly convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Pugh gives the definition of nearly uniformly convergence:

$f_n:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ converges nearly uniformly to $f$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ if for each $\epsilon >0$ there is an $\epsilon$-set $S\subset [a,b]$ (that is $mS < \epsilon$)such that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly as x varies in $S^c$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$.

So I can see that the condition of nearly uniformly convergence is weaker than almost uniformly convergence, which means uniformly convergence on the complement of a zero set. But how do we contrast those two? Can we have a sequence which is nearly uniformly convergent but not almost?

Comment: How about the sequence $f_n:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f_n(x)=\min{ \big\{n,\frac{1}{x}}\big\}$? Where "almost" is defined wrt Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I think you are right, it is not uniformly convergent on $(0,1]$, and it is nearly uniformly convergent.

Comment: Yes, it converges nearly uniformly but not almost uniformly, since the complement of any measure zero set contains points arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: A similar example: $f_n(x) := x^n$, $x \in [0,1]$.